# GraphQL How to get all countries based on a selected continent code

Tags: graphql

I am using the following GraphQL schema and want to find out how to get all the countries based on the continent code.

https://countries.trevorblades.com/

```
query GetCountriesByContinent($code: String!) {
  
    countries(filter: {
      continent: {
        ???
      }
    })
  
}
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: The following code works but I am not sure how continent is match against the code.

```
query GetCountriesByContinent($code: String!) {
  
      countries(filter: {
        continent: { eq: $code }
      }) {
    name 
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

It might be that behind the scene when you compare a type with something it always compare using the ID field.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand your query let's break it down

```
countries(filter: {
        continent: { eq: $code }
      })
```

1. `countries` - find all countries
2. `filter` - filtered by
3. `continent` - continent (field)
4. `eq` - equals to
5. `$code` - code (passed as argument)

In this API field `code` acts as an ID so behind the scenes they compare by `continent.code`. That logic of comparison and filtering is happening on the server-side implementation. The developer of that API can choose how he wants to implement comparison

You can also explore docs and schema on the right-side panel in Grahpql Playground and you can see possible options:

```
input CountryFilterInput {
  code: StringQueryOperatorInput
  currency: StringQueryOperatorInput
  continent: StringQueryOperatorInput
}
```

That means you can filter countries by `code` `currency` and `continent`

```
input StringQueryOperatorInput {
  eq: String
  ne: String
  in: [String]
  nin: [String]
  regex: String
  glob: String
}
```

- `eq`: is exactly the filter value.
- `ne`: is anything except for the filter value.
- `in`: matches any element in given array
- `nin`: matches none of the elements in given array
- `lt`: is lower than the filter value
- `lte`: is lower than or equal to the filter value
- `gt`: is greater than the filter value
- `gte`: is greater than or equal to the filter value
- `regex`: matches given JavaScript regex
- `glob`: matches given micromatch pattern

It looks like query filters used in Gatsby to get more details
Reference docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/#supported-comparators

Comment: So code matches the ID property of the country.